# Shell Scripting pattern for date

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, grep

I am trying to make a script that asks from the user to type a date. This date should be typed like this: `DDMMYYHHMM`. For example if it's `15-12-2018 13:05`. It should be written like this `1512181305`. I'm trying to find the correct pattern to accept only this kind of format. I was thinking something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash  
read date 
[[ $date =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]      || exit 1;
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: That's a somewhat naive approach - it allows for the 45th of the 19th month ;) at the 98th minute of the 32nd hour ...

Comment: Btw, in terms of natural sorting `YYYYMMDDHHMM` would make more sense - just saying.

Comment: Why not use `date -d"$user_input"` to validate the user entered the date in an acceptable form and then you can format the date however you need with date in a *command substitution*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
read date
[[ $date =~ ^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[0-9][0-9](2[0-3]|[01][0-9])[0-5][0-9]$ ]] || exit 1;
```

With this :

```
Day could be between 1 and 31 --> (0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])
Month between 1 and 12        --> (0[1-9]|1[0-2])
Year between 0 and 99         --> [0-9][0-9]
Hour between 0 and 23         --> (2[0-3]|[01][0-9])
Minutes between 0 and 59      --> [0-5][0-9]
```